# Cannot creating a config file in Laravel File Manager

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was tried to use a Laravel File Manager and i reach the step when i have to create a config file by typing:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

It said successful but i can't find in `config/lpm.php`. When I click the button it give me a 404 in this address:

```
http://blog.dev/file-manager?type=image
```

so what can i do to fix this problems? heres javascript file if it needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Define function to open filemanager window
        var lfm = function(options, cb) {
            var route_prefix = (options && options.prefix) ? options.prefix : '/laravel-filemanager';
            window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + options.type || 'file', 'FileManager', 'width=900, height=600');
            window.SetUrl = cb;
        };

        // Define LFM summernote button
        var LFMButton = function(context) {
            var ui = $.summernote.ui;
            var button = ui.button({
                contents: '<i class="note-icon-picture"></i> ',
                tooltip: 'Insert image with filemanager',
                click: function() {

                    lfm({type: 'image', prefix: '/file-manager'}, function(url, path) {
                        context.invoke('insertImage', url);
                    });

                }
            });
            return button.render();
        };

        // Initialize summernote with LFM button in the popover button group
        // Please note that you can add this button to any other button group you'd like
        $('#summernote-editor').summernote({
            toolbar: [
                ['popovers', ['lfm']],
            ],
            buttons: {
                lfm: LFMButton
            }
        })

    });
</script>
```